# Open Source ISDN Protocol Testing

Tags: testing, asterisk, isdn

I have a very specific requirement to test ISDN PRI interfaces for protocols like Q.931 and specific protocols like ARINC 746.

I was wondering if there are any open source tools these the above protocols. Likes of Asterisk on a Linux Box having PRI ports?

Answer (score 1):

If you are to use an Open source product,First You have to connect ISDN PRI interface to a PC, through a telephony card. There are lot of Telephony cards available in the market,
`Digium, Sangoma, Dialogic, Donjin, Avaya`, etc.

Most of those commercial hardware products has its own testing/configuring tools for ISDN PRI, SS7, etc. So, you may not require a Open Source product extensively.

Also there are Open Source products like, FreeSwitch, AsteriX, OpenPBX, you can used to test those.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the details of the protocols you mention, but Asterisk has an impressive debug output of ISDN details when you run it with one of the Digium cards. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get a Sangoma telephony card you can do it using wanpipemon sangoma tool and the well known wireshark. If have a digium card will can get just q931 using dahdi_pcap -p ldap.